# jQuery: Each loop pause till finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

I have the following jQuery loop but inside each loop-action I have user interaction and the code should wait till the user interaction should be finished. Is there a possibility to pause the loop or is it somehow other possible to realize it?

```
jQuery.each([345, 897, 345 /* ... */], function(index, value) {
    // User interaction, need to wait the user finishing/answer

    // Here is a jQuery UI dialog with an input field in it
    // After the user entered their value and hit the submit button
    // which fires an own callback which could also continue the loop somehow?
});
```

Comment: I assume you're using the loop because you don't know how many elements to anticipate?

Comment: @Johannes. why do you assume it???

Comment: Because if you know how many elements there will be you could just code it our without a loop. Granted, that's annoying, but you can't just stop a loop without any other sort of intervention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to abandon `each` and handle this yourself.  One option would be something like this:

```
var curIndex = 0;
var ids = [345, 897, 345 /* ... */];

function doNext(){

  // check curIndex here to make sure you haven't completed the list, etc.

  var id = ids[curIndex++];

  // do stuff with this id
}

// THIS IS SOME SORT OF CODE EXECUTED WHEN THE "USER INTERACTION" FINISHES
function interactionDone(){
   doNext();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As javascript is single threaded, the only user action you could put in the each loop would be either an `alert` or `confirm`.  If those don't fill your requirement, you'll need to handle the each loop yourself.  For example:

```
//assume foo = [345, 897, 345 /* ... */]
var i = 0;
function handleNextFoo() {
    i++;
    if(i < foo.length) {
        //Do something with foo[i]
        //now we wait for use action to call the callbackFromUserAction()
    }
}
function callbackFromUserAction() {
    //Handle user action
    handleNextFoo();
}
```

Disclaimer: Naming conventions should be handled for your product to scope variables and make them more usable.

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit on why single thread would be a problem here, and why ’alert’ and ’confirm’ are immune? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just build yourself a quick iterator object so you can handle array with ease.

```
var iterator = function(array) {
    this.array = array;
    this.len = array.length;
    this.index = 0;
    return this;
};

iterator.prototype.next = function(callback) {
    callback.call(null, this.array[this.index]);
    this.index++;
    if (this.index == this.len) this.onend.call(null, this.array);
    return this;
};

iterator.prototype.onend = function() {
    alert('done');
};

var iterate = new iterator(arr);

iterate.next(function(val) {
    console.log(val);
});
```

Here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/KfrVN/1/

But otherwise like DMoses pointed out only alert/confirm can stop a loop because they are javascript user actions, so iterating your own way is the only approach.